# Why some of my images are being ignored in Tensorflow when i have images not being ignored in the same folders?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

I have data inside 2 folders (Training with 10000 images and Validation with 1000 images) and in each of these folders I have 10 folders (the respective classes).
I put all this data into a dataframe to use later.
It turns out that some images in certain folders at the moment I use "flow_from_dataframe" in Tensorflow are assumed to have invalid names and are therefore ignored.

And I try to access any image outside Tensorflow, for example by simply making the image open and I still can't access certain files when the path is completely correct

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("D:\Ensino Superior\ISCTE-IUL\Mestrado em Engenharia Informatica\Tese\Testagem\TomatoLeafDisease\data\Train\Tomato___Tomato_mosaic_virus\Tomato___Tomato_mosaic_virus_original_f16eeb0f-5219-4a81-9941-351b3d9ba5fc___PSU_CG 2089.JPG_a88e521f-cec2-4755-871f-782de8192056.JPG") 
im.show()
```

[Output when trying to acess an image outside Tensorflow code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai6T1.png)

[The dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tejh.png)

I have researched and seen that using abs path could help and make it work however even then some images are being ignored, what can I do so that no image is ignored ?

Code before the output with the error:

```
def create_gen():
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input,
        validation_split=0.2
    )
    test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input
    )

    train_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Class',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=0,
        subset='training',
        rotation_range=30, # Uncomment to use data augmentation
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
    )

    val_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Class',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=0,
        subset='validation',
        rotation_range=30, # Uncomment to use data augmentation
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
    )

    test_images = test_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=validation_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Class',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=False
    )

    return train_generator,test_generator,train_images

pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
include_top=False,
weights='imagenet',
pooling='avg'

train_generator,test_generator,train_images,val_images,test_images = create_gen()
```

[Output after using "flow_from_data_frame" with Tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MThuX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out. It was due to the fact that the path to the images and the image name itself was too long.

Answer (score 0):

Your generators are incorrect. For example you have this code.

```
 train_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col='Filepath',
        y_col='Class',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=0,
        subset='training',
        rotation_range=30, # Uncomment to use data augmentation
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
```

Parameters rotation_range,  width_shift_range, height_shift_range, shear_range, horizontal_flip  and fill_mode do not belong in .flow_from_dataframe. They should be placed in ImageDataGenerator as shown below

```
train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(        preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input,
        validation_split=0.2, rotation_range=30, zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,  height_shift_range=0.2,  shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest" )
```

For the problem with paths to images try to run this. I use sdir as the directory containing your data, just substitute the correct directory name.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
sdir=r'C:\Temp\balls\train' # set this to you directory
good_image_count=0
bad_image_count=0
processed_count=0
bad_image_list=[]
classlist=os.listdir(sdir)
for klass in classlist:
    print ('processing class directory ', klass)
    classpath=os.path.join(sdir, klass)
    if os.path.isdir(classpath):
        flist=os.listdir(classpath)
        print (' number of files in class directory ', klass,' is ', len(flist))
        for f in flist:
            processed_count +=1
            fpath=os.path.join(classpath, f)
            if os.path.isfile(fpath):
                try:
                    image=Image.open(fpath)
                    image.verify()
                    good_image_count +=1
                except:
                    bad_image_count +=1
                    bad_image_list.append(fpath)
            else:
                print('in class directory ', klass, ' you have sub directories, you should only have files in it')
    else:
        print ('In the sdir you have files, you should only have class subdirectories in sdir')
print(processed_count, ' files were processed') 
print(good_image_count, ' files were valid image files')
print(bad_image_count, ' files were invalid images or paths did not exist')
for f in bad_image_list:
    print (f)
```

Comment: Thanks Geery P. But i already did that to confirm and compare and yes the number of files printed is the number of files that really are in the folder.

Comment: see amended answer

Comment: I use your code, and it says i have sub directories in one of the trains folders (the "Tomato__Tomato_mosaic_virus"), but i only have files in there. If you want to see the dataset that i am using, the data set is this one https://www.kaggle.com/kaustubhb999/tomatoleaf and for what i can see the folder with the files that are giving problems in your code and in my code when a try to access all the files is the  "Tomato__Tomato_mosaic_virus".

Comment: You must have copied the dataset incorrectly. Go to the dataset on Kagle and select code then select notebook EfficientNet B3 Test Accuracy=99%  or go directly to https://www.kaggle.com/gpiosenka/efficientnet-b3-test-accuracy-99. It has the complete code to test the images, build the dataframes, build the generators, build the model and train it.

Comment: Sorry but that page does not exist